# Installing tensorflow R studio

Tags: r, tensorflow, rstudio, report

I am trying to use the following code to install tensorflow on R studio, but I am getting an error "Error: installation of Python 3.9.16 failed." Can anyone help assist such that I can install successfully on R?

```
library(keras)
library(tfdatasets)
library(reticulate)
path_to_python <- install_python()
virtualenv_create("r-reticulate", python = path_to_python)
library(tensorflow)
reticulate::install_miniconda()
install_tensorflow(envname = "r-reticulate")
```